# Nginx check if Cloudflare forward or direct IP and limit accordingly

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

I am aware of the headers `CF-Connecting-IP`, `$binary_remote_addr`, `http_x_forwarded_for`

I want to make a setting:

```
limit_req_zone $http_x_forwarded_for zone=k_request_limit_per_ip:10m rate=400r/s;
limit_conn_zone $http_x_forwarded_for zone=k_connection_limit_per_ip:10m;
```

---

But Cloudflare isn't the only place that this machine is going to be accessed, so I want to limit direct access too.
Is there a way to write something like:

```
if(header == `X-Forwarded-For`) {
  limit_req_zone $http_x_forwarded_for zone=k_request_limit_per_ip:10m rate=400r/s;
} else {
  limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=k_request_limit_per_ip:10m rate=400r/s;
}
```

Or would something like this work:

```
  limit_req_zone $http_x_forwarded_for zone=http_zone:10m rate=400r/s;
  limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=binary_zone:10m rate=400r/s;
```

An alternative would be to fully allow all Cloudflare IP addresses. And limit the Non-Cloudflare  IP addresses.

Good source:

- [NGINX rate limiting doesn't work when using Cloudflare. I can bring down my site with a simple `ab` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61620292/nginx-rate-limiting-doesnt-work-when-using-cloudflare-i-can-bring-down-my-site)

Comment: have your tried to use a `map` for that? You could use a map to the define the limit-req-zone variable and use it in your limit_req_zone.

Comment: Or `njs` with `js_set` do define the correct req_zone based on given inputs.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with those `techs`. So I haven't tried them. Got a possible solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make use of the ngx_real_ip_module.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html

With this you can specify the Cloudflare CIDRs to be allowed to override the `binary_remote_addr` with the value from `X-Forwarded-For`. Make sure you have this check in place. Config could look like:

```
set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/12;
set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 2400:cb00::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2606:4700::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2803:f800::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2a06:98c0::/29;
set_real_ip_from 2c0f:f248::/32;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive off;
```

Cloudflare IPs can change, this command will automatically update them into `cloudflare_ips.conf`:

```
cat /dev/null > cloudflare_ips.conf && curl -s https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v4 | while read ip; do echo "set_real_ip_from $ip;" >> cloudflare_ips.conf; done && curl -s https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v6 | while read ip; do echo "set_real_ip_from $ip;" >> cloudflare_ips.conf; done && printf "real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;\nreal_ip_recursive off;\n" >> cloudflare_ips.conf
```

Your rate limit config can use the `binary_remote_addr` variable. If the client comes via cloudflare, CFs IP will be replaced with the IP from the Header. If the client connects directly the client IP will be used. If a client tries to send a `X-Forwarded-For` Header that one will not be accepted as the clients IP does not match any CIDR from your `cloudflare_ips.conf` file.