# Nginx limit_req_zone using http_x_forwarded_for is not working for me

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am trying to add rate limiting to my service since it sometimes gets bursty calls from specific ips
This is my nginx configuration -

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/https.conf:
    content: |
      map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default       "upgrade";
        ""            "";
      }

       limit_req_zone $request_method$uri zone=employees:1m rate=75r/s;
       limit_req_zone $http_x_forwarded_for zone=employees_by_ip:1m rate=5r/s;

       limit_req_log_level error;
       limit_req_status 403;

      # HTTPS server
      server {
        listen       443;

        gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
          set $year $1;
          set $month $2;
          set $day $3;
          set $hour $4;
        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log logger-json;

        ssl                  on;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;

        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

        proxy_http_version    1.1;

        proxy_set_header    Connection        $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Host              $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;

        location /employees/configs {
          limit_req zone=employees burst=75 nodelay;
          limit_req zone=employees_by_ip burst=5 nodelay;
          proxy_pass http://docker;
        }

        location /employees {
          limit_req zone=employees burst=75 nodelay;
          limit_req zone=employees_by_ip burst=5 nodelay;
          proxy_pass http://docker;
        }

        # Everything else
        location / {
          proxy_pass http://docker;
        }
      }
```

The strange part is this works in one of my environments but not in another and I am not able to figure out why it wouldn't. Please help, I am kind of stuck

Answer (score 0):

Limit requests based on request method and URI is not good idea. If you would like to limit connctions for specific ips use something like `$binary_remote_addr`.

Are you sure you want to limit the number of request per second to **5**? So let draw that out:

```
HTTP1.1 GET / --> index.html (contains images, css, js)
HTTP1.1 GET /style.css ->
HTTP1.1 GET /header.png
HTTP1.1 GET /avatar.png
HTTP1.1 GET /script.js
HTTP1.1 GET /date.js --> ERROR Limit exeeded.
```

You can use the `burst` and `nodeplay` directive to tune this behavior in your `limit_req`. We have a great blog post about it:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/

On top of that, be carefull with `X-Forwarded-For`. This header can be manipulated by any client and can lead to an Rate-Limit bypass vulnerability.

I have just answered another rate-limit-question on SO.

[Nginx check if Cloudflare forward or direct IP and limit accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66692200/nginx-check-if-cloudflare-forward-or-direct-ip-and-limit-accordingly)

In this thread I have explainde the Problems with `X-Forwarded-For` and how to mitigate.