# How to get Nginx HTTP Basic auth to recognise a permitted client's IP on the far side of a load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, aws-elb

I have configured Nginx to require HTTP Basic auth for a website I'm working on that isn't yet public. I included an `allow` clause to permit the IP address of the company's head office to view the site without entering a password. This worked initially, however after placing the Nginx server behind a load balancer (AWS ELB), the IP address Nginx sees is actually the IP address of the load balancer, NOT of the requesting web client - so it stopped working.

I have the real IP address of the client in the `X-Forwarded-For` header. Is there a way to get Nginx to recognise the client and let it in without logging in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the NGINX real-IP module for that.

I have described the use of this module here [Stackoverflow #66692200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66692200/nginx-check-if-cloudflare-forward-or-direct-ip-and-limit-accordingly/66809489#66809489)

Basically you need to do

```
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive off;
```

You should check if you are able to set the ELB-IP as the only one that will be allowed to send the `X-Forwarded-For` header. Find out more information [here](https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-find-load-balancer-IP/)